# Adding interactive elements to Storm topology

Tags: apache-storm

I have a topology which saves data it is unable to process at the moment to a special database. Once I add the capability to process the data, I would like to be able to tell the topology "Go and process a block of leftover data from [time A] to [time B]".

**Is there a "stormic"** (is that a word?) **way to implement this? For example by adding interactive elements (buttons, input fields) to the Storm UI?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think anything like this is built in. What you could likely do it write your unprocessable records to somewhere (e.g. Kafka) until you can process them. When you can process them, you could make Storm pick them up by adding the unprocessable records topic(s) to the Kafka input topics, or start another copy of your topology that only consumes from the unprocessable records data source.

Comment: Thank you. I'm considering adding a RabbitMQ spout, which will consume and dispatch commands which will trigger certain actions in the topology. Does that sound like a reasonable idea?

Comment: Maybe? Adding a RabbitMQ spout would probably be fine (might want to check Google, looks like other people have also looked at this). Your description of what the spout will do isn't specific enough for me to have an opinion on, i.e. I don't understand how having a spout emit commands into the topology will solve your problem.

Comment: The idea is that I will then post commands into the queue which will ask 'spout DataInput, please re-emit data with timestamps T1 - T2'.

Comment: Okay. That sounds fine, but I would still think that a solution that doesn't require a custom spout would be nicer. I don't see a reason it couldn't work though.